# How to reduce the page loading time in drupal for firsttime

Tags: drupal-7

I am developing a website in drupal7, it takes 8 to 10 seconds to load each page the first time, next time it takes 1 to 2 seconds. I have enabled cache, css compression and JS compression.

Please provide suggestion to reduce the time of first time loading.

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps by which you can improve your site performance:

1. If you are using image on your site so please try to upload image in
   KB or Bytes.
2. Use http compression.
3. Use cache module like varnich, mamcache, APC etc.
4. Enable default cache system of drupal (in your case it is already
   enabled).
5. Enable CSS and JS compression (in your case it is already
   enabled).

For further details please follow these 2 links

- [drupal.stackexchange.com/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow)
- [5-ways-to-improve-performance-in-drupal](http://friendlymachine.net/posts/2011/5-ways-to-improve-performance-in-drupal)